# Error trying to unwrap an optional value

Tags: swift

```
import  UIKit

class About: UITableViewController {
    var FollowUpArray = [String]()
    var aboutUsArray = [String] ()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        aboutUsArray = ["hello","hello","hello"]
        FollowUpArray = ["hello1","hello2","hello3"]
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return aboutUsArray.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var Cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

        Cell.textLabel?.text = aboutUsArray[indexPath.row]

        return Cell
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        var indexPath : NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!
```

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

```
        var DestViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! AboutUss

        DestViewController.FirstString = FollowUpArray[indexPath.row]
    }
```

the fatal error occurs when i want to go back from this table view to another view controller Xcode does not allow it.

Comment: The error is telling you that the result of `self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()` is `nil`. When you force-unwrap it with `!`, you crash. Please format your question and your code better.

Comment: Riley has said everything. But either the table view or the returned index path is nil.

Comment: @RileyAvron how could i change my code so i wouldn't get that error?

Comment: Are you calling `deselectRowAtIndexPath` method?

Comment: i want it to deselect row at index path so it doesn't think it needs an index. @sasquatch

Comment: Sorry I couldn't get you. Are you calling `deselectRowAtIndexPath` method in your code?